# How can i sort this multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, usort

i can't make the sorting on this multidimensional array, i need to sort from lower to Higher by "packagenumber" value

This is my array:

[image]

[image]

I'm trying with usort:

```
uasort($data, function($a, $b) {
            return strcmp($data['packagenumber'], $data['packagenumber']);
        });
```

Comment: why are you using `strcmp` for sorting integers? just use `return $a['packagenumber'] - $b['packagenumber']`to sort integers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should use usort as you dont need to maintain the indexes of your array.

Then, something like this should work:

```
function int_compare($a, $b) {
    return $a['packagenumber'] - $b['packagenumber'];
}

usort($data, 'int_compare');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
usort($data, function($a, $b) {
            return $a['packagenumber'] > $b['packagenumber'];
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you, like myself lots of times, find yourself in a situation where you need to do this kind of sorting inside a class and need to define the comparing function as a member of the class, you can then call it like this:

```
function mainFunction(){
$array = array(
            ['id' => 5, 'name' => 'Name', 'packagenumber' => 2],
            ['id' => 6, 'name' => 'Another', 'packagenumber' => 3],
            ['id' => 7, 'name' => 'Again', 'packagenumber' => 1]);

usort($array, array($this, 'int_compare'));
}

function int_compare($a, $b) {
        return $a['packagenumber'] - $b['packagenumber'];
}
```

`$this` in this case is a reference to the class containing the comparing function

HIH

Answer (score 0):

You can extract a column, sort it, then sort the original on that:

```
array_multisort(array_column($data, 'packagenumber'), $data);
```